# T-SQL Update Nvarchar column with Decimal separated text ('cmi.core.lesson_status') Error

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I am working with Moodle database in SQL Server 2008 R2. I am trying to update a `NVarchar(255) NOT NULL` column with decimal separated string values like 'cmi.core.lesson_status' but always end up with an error.

```
col = N'cmi.core.lesson_status' ==> doesn't save
```

Strange but if I remove 's' at the end it saves

```
col = N'cmi.core.lesson_statu' ==> saves but no 's' at the end
```

If I remove one decimal it saves

```
col = N'cmicore.lesson_status' ==> saves
```

If I remove one decimal and add more text then it saves as well

```
col = N'cmicore.lesson_statusaaaaaaaa' ==> works
```

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: "always end up with an error." - and would you care to share that error with us?

Comment: Is there a trigger on that field?

Comment: Oh, i am sorry i forgot to add error 'Error converting data type varchar to real'. Oh, mybad, yes it has trigger on it. let me check the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the helpful tip 'Alex K'.

It was nothting to do with NVarchar variable.

The problem was with a Real variable @code when used with string data. I simply added CAST and it worked

```
@strSQL = N'code is' + @code
```

and I changed it to

```
@strSQL = N'code is' + CAST(@code As Varchar(12))
```

Thanks for the help.